# CSS: center an inline-block div inside it's parent div

Tags: css, css-float

(Code: http://jsfiddle.net/T4hrK/)

I've looked and looked, and can't find how. I have an outer `div`, in which I want to center an inner `div`. The inner `div` contains a bunch of inline elements (like images in a gallery, say), which I am willing to make , or inline-block elements, or floating block elements, whatever it takes.

However, when there are "too many" inline elements inside the inner div, it will wrap them on a new line, and here's the catch: it will *not* size itself to exactly contain the result, but rather size itself to fit its parent width. When that's the case, I can't center it inside its parent, since it has its parent width.

What I want is for the inner inline elements to be left-aligned inside their containing `div`, but for that `div` to exactly enclose them, so that I can center it inside its parent.

Example:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; padding:2px;">
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid green;">
    <span>1234567</span>
    <span>1234567</span>
    <span>1234567</span>
    <span>1234567</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The inner (green) `div` is "too wide": it could have been narrow, but as it is I cannot center inside the red `div`.

In this example, of course, the `span`'s are my images, the green `div` is what should exactly wrap/contain/enclose them, and the red `div` is what I want to center the green `div` in.

Comment: But if the red div is too small how would it be centered?

Comment: I believe he wants it to look like this, but presumably without the forced line break: http://jsfiddle.net/T4hrK/3/.

Comment: I dont really understand the question :/

Comment: @JonathanS. -- correct. That's exactly what I want, but don't want to force line-breaks because that logic would be incorrect given different "red" container widths. (Will not be "fluid").

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Gxcwk/
That collapses based on size of inner elements within that inner div.
I just made the inner elements

```
float:left; margin:2px 5px;
```

so you can see the division between them. I'd think that you'd be placing images that are equally sized inside anyway, if you want a neat looking grid.

Bear in mind that's only going to happen on page load or page refresh. Cool library if you're looking for something more fluid or responsive: jQuery masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Not really, no. Note that if you make the last element a `<span>` (which I have to -- I don't know in advance when to break a row), and make the width say 200px, then the elements in the first row are not centered. I'll have a look at masonry, thanks.

Comment: This answer help me out a lot, was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `text-align: center;` to the parent div, as per this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T4hrK/12/